# Get a web page via socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets

Update: for some website it works

I have to do a client via socket Java that has to "get" (print on the shell) a web page. The problem is that when I execute the code, I have this response:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Cache-Control: private 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer 
Location: http://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=9CrqWcCNEabCXuCXq5AP 
Content-Length: 266 
Date: Fri, 20 Oct 2017 16:57:24 GMT 
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;dcr=0&amp;ei=9CrqWcCNEabCXuCXq5AP">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

What is the problem? How can I fix it?
This is my program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Meteo  {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Socket sock = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;

    try {
        sock = new Socket("www.google.com", 80);
        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

        br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is));
        pw = new PrintWriter(os);

        pw.println("GET / HTTP/1.0 \r\n");
        pw.println("\r\n");
        pw.flush();

        String l;
        while ((l=br.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(l);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    sock.close();
    br.close();
    pw.close();
}
```

}

Comment: You're better off using `wget` or `curl` or some such. However, if you must use Java, look up the [302 HTTP result code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302). The server tells you that you need to look for this document in a different location. So you have to use your code again, but with the contents of `Location:` field.

Comment: yeah, i did it, but the program doesn't end... no response at all. :/

Comment: Try doing it with a browser. Also, where does it hang? Reading the response? Connecting?

Comment: There is a great Unix command line tool `nc` - you can experiment with writing/reading to sockets in your shell: `echo -n "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc host.example.com 80`

Comment: Btw, your code opens `www.google.com`, but the redirect goes to `www.google.it`. That could be your problem.